# python 3 - .swf to html

Tags: html, python-3.x, flash, urllib

Is there a way to decompile flash files into html in python 3?

I'm using urllib to gather html data from a website and would like to include flash content .. in html format, as part of the rest of the html content, preferably without downloading the file.

The few packages available are old and not made for python 3 or are not web based.

There are many free online decompiler tools for this so I thought it would have been easier to find code for this.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

As a workaround solution I have found this:
http://www.nowrap.de/flare.html
Which is a command line swf to html converter. I'm considering calling it as a `subprocess` unless someone has a better idea?

Comment: **Flare** is a decompiler tool, not converter, for old versions of Flash (7 and 8) too. In general, I don't think you can convert working SWF application to working HTML application.

Comment: Hi, sorry I mean't to say decompiler. I'll correct this in the post title

Comment: Your best bet is probably https://github.com/jindrapetrik/jpexs-decompiler/wiki/Commandline-arguments then.

Comment: can this be used in python without a calling it with a subprocess?

Comment: No. It's Java-based application and I don't think it has a Python module. You might want to email its author to be sure, it won't hurt you.